# How to break down validation checks in Angular7?

Tags: regex, angular7, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I have an input that I have to display visually that the user has met multiple requirements with icons.

The regex I'm using is:

```
'^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9]+$'
```

But, I need to be able to show that the user has entered one number, one alpha character, no spaces before or after string, and has 4 different characters. When the user full fills one of the above requirements and indicator icon next to that requirement must turn green. I've looked everywhere for an example. Is there a simple check I can do in an ngIf statement? I can't seem to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how you're going to handle lighting the tree 1 bulb at a time,
but the regex for this requirement `and has 4 different characters`
is this.

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=[a-zA-Z0-9]+$).*?(.).*?(?!\1)(.).*?(?!\1|\2)(.).*?(?!\1|\2|\3)(.).*?$
```

Explained

```
 ^                             # BOS

 (?= .* [a-z] )                # At least a lower case letter
 (?= .* [A-Z] )                # At least a upper case letter
 (?= .* [0-9] )                # At least a number
 (?= [a-zA-Z0-9]+ $ )          # All chars must be letters or numbers

 .*? 
 ( . )                         # (1), First unique char

 .*? 
 (?! \1 )
 ( . )                         # (2), Second unique char

 .*? 
 (?! \1 | \2 )
 ( . )                         # (3), Third unique char

 .*? 
 (?! \1 | \2 | \3 )
 ( . )                         # (4), Fourth unique char

 .*? 

 $                             # EOS
```

Comment: Thank you, this isn't something I generally do where I work, but have been tasked with it. This certainly gets me much closer to the finish line than I was and really appreciate it. I'm concerned about they way this is set up and I may circle back with my UX team and see about changing the tree bulbs.

Comment: @fRyanIndustries8 - When the field generates an activity interrupt (signal ?), Run 4 separate regex in the field. First off don't let any invalid characters get into the field. Find `[^a-zA-Z0-9]+` replace with nothing. Then do the separate light regexes. 1) Lower case `^.*[a-z]`, 2) Upper case `^.*[A-Z]`, 3) Number `^.*[0-9]`, Finally, 4 unique, use the regex above.  The regex above is also used as a _Final Validation_. The process doesn't have to be difficult.

Comment: I have been trying to find an example like the description above. Do you know of any resources that reflect the way you described? I'm at a bit of a loss. I'm not looking for an exact answer, but more of how I would go about this in Angular 7

Comment: I would look at the events available to the control on the form, and put handlers in for the ones you need. Something like change events, key up/down events, stuff like that. I'm an MFC programmer, of which JS has the watered down versions available to me, and I'm not a JS programmer ( by choice, it's junk ).